# Characters run together in Libreoffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice

In LibreOffice Writer under Ubuntu 20.04 and LibreOffice 6.4.3.2, the characters are all jumbled together. Can the characters and spacing be fixed? Screen image below.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Does this help? https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/28369/change-character-spacing/